# Surface to be printed appears with virtual Thickness?

Tags: graphics3d, 3d-printing

```
   f[x_, y_, z_] := x + Cos[z]^2 + y^2
    ContourPlot3D[f[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
      Mesh -> {4, 4, 4}] /. Line[p_] :> Tube[p, .1]
```

In the image we see some nominal Thickness for the  surface although no Thickness is specified. It was not bargained for, a sort of non-WYSIWYG situation. We should be able to see  through the Tubes to the back side. Can we to do away with it?

If 3d printed, will it print with an arbitrary spurious thickness? Thanks for help.

Comment: does `ContourPlot3D[f[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
    BoundaryStyle -> None,    Mesh -> {4, 4, 4}] /.  Line[p_] :> {CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[.5, Red], Tube[p, .1]} ` give what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `MeshStyle` and `MeshStyle`

```
ContourPlot3D[f[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},Mesh -> {4, 4, 4},MeshStyle -> Opacity[.5],MeshStyle -> None] /. Line[p_] :> Tube[p, .1]
```

[image]

`ContourStyle->None` only shows the tubes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Tube` as a directive in setting `MeshStyle`:

```
ContourPlot3D[f[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> {4, 4, 4}, PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface",
 MeshStyle -> ({#, #, #} &@{CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[.5, Red],  Tube[.1]})]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can post-process to replace mesh lines with `Tube`s:

```
ContourPlot3D[f[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> {4, 4, 4}, PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface"] /. 
 Line[p_] :> {CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[.5, Red], Tube[p, .1]}
```

[image]

Replace `PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface"` with `Method -> Extrusion -> .3` to get

[image]